# Can the CPU use the dedicated GPU Memory?

Tags: memory, gpu, memory-management

[Inspired by this question](https://superuser.com/q/1545812/269011) So the GPU can use the main RAM as extra memory? So can the reverse happen? Can the CPU use the dedicated GPU memory as faster or extra RAM?

[image]

In task manager I have 4GB of GPU memory, can I use this as RAM?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Quora: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-allocate-some-of-my-VRAM-as-RAM-I-have-8-GB-of-each-RAM-prices-are-increasing-and-I-don-t-need-all-the-VRAM-Can-I-turn-VRAM-into-RAM

You can't use the VRAM as RAM, because PCI isn't designed for doing this. The speeds would be extremely slow and would not be usable.

You can, however, use VRAM as a RAM disk, and then use that as either paged RAM or by using Windows ReadyBoost. The application to do this is here: https://github.com/prsyahmi/GpuRamDrive

Comment: Just to add to this - this probably won't work if you are using the GPU for anything